# Canvas change lineWidth on drawing after it has been drawn

Tags: canvas, stroke

In canvas, is it possible to change the lineWidth of a drawing?

Example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

It has already been drawn, but I want to change the lineWidth after it is drawn.

Comment: What's stopping you from changing it after drawing?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about redrawing the line with a new line width, that's quite possible.  You can use `requestAnimationFrame`.  Here's a little aimation to show you what I mean.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(timestamp) {
    var period = 0.5;
    var t = Date.now()%(period*1000)/(period*1000);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineWidth = 15+5*Math.sin(t*2*Math.PI);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll need to re-draw it with a different line width.

The reason is that `path` cannot be stored as a variable, so you cannot call `ctx.stroke()` on the same path multiple times. Animation frames are probably your best bet.

Comment: Now you **can** save a path to a variable with the recently adopted [`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes). ;-)

Comment: Damn, I need to catch up :) Thanks!