# How can I change line width in a canvas in HTML with a click event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the line width in canvas from 5 to 10 from a click event but it's not working in JavaScript

```
function draw(e) {
     if (!painting) {
         return;
     }

     exitdraw(e);
     c.lineWidth = 5;
     c.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
     c.lineCap = 'round';
     c.strokeStyle = 'aqua';
     c.stroke();
     c.beginPath();
     c.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}

    //this is the listener i want to change the linewidth
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click',function(){

        canvas.getContext('2d').lineWidth = 10;
    })
```

Comment: Share the full code so people can help. But looks like you need to make one variable and manipulate that. something like `let lineW=5; c.lineWidth= lineW;` and manipulate that variable on the btn click event.

Comment: to increase the lineWidth you need to clear the canvas and then redraw it again. that's how canvas work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canvas change lineWidth on drawing after it has been drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38691276/215552).

Comment: i solved it and didn't need to clear it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<button onclick="changeWidth()">Change Width</button>
<br />
<canvas height="150" id="canvas" width="200"></canvas>

<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    var lineWidth = 5;

    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.arc(100, 75, 32, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    draw();

    function changeWidth() {
        lineWidth = 10;
        draw();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas doesn't store references to what you draw on it so it's impossible to change property that will affect what you draw.

What I mean is in order to change some drawing in your canvas you should render it again with your new style.

Because you use client data on your draw function you should store the data (clientX/Y etc...) in variables (or you may prefer one object that stores all data) and call that function again, but you need to refactor your function to get `lineWidth` as a param.

Answer (score 0):

Trouble is, you are changing the value after content is drawn. For changes to take affect, you may want to redraw the content after a change. Like:

```
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    canvas.getContext('2d').lineWidth = 10;
    draw(); // apply changes by redrawing
})
```

And of course you should omit the `c.lineWidth = 5` line from draw function to not to override change. Perhaps do `c.lineWidth = 5` in a initializer function ot smt as a default value.

Answer (score 0):

thanks you all for help but i solved it just saved the value in  variable and manipulate it  like  @Whatatimetobealive said